# Могут ли быть проблемы с одновременными изменениями в базе данных?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, теория

Ситуация теоретическая: есть, условно, тысячи две человек в таблице БД, при обращении одного из них в другой таблице будет уменьшаться число, если оно станет нулём, то пользователю будет выдаваться ошибка. Могут ли быть проблемы с тем, что одновременно много человек будут это выполнять? Может ли быть такая ситуация, что в графе будет единица, а два человека одновременно выполнят запрос на вычитание?

Comment: Может, если не принимать мер по ограничению одновременного доступа к данным

Comment: @ArchDemon а каким образом вовремя успеть ограничить доступ? Условно, несколько человек крутят колесо с подарками, коих ограниченное количество, и чтобы не получилось так, что подарок остался один, но успели нажать два человека, или это физически невозможно, кто-то всё равно будет на уровне системы раньше и оно успеет просчитать, что там уже 0?

Comment: Читайте про транзакции вообще и уровень изоляции в частности.

Comment: @Mr.Code Зависит от вашего кода. Если вы без транзакций и блокировок на чтение сначала считываете значение, потом проверяете и пишите в БД измененное значение, то у вас может быть ситуация, что один скрипт считает значение, в этот момент второй то же считает и оба увидят 1. после чего оба вычтут 1 и запишут. В БД может и 0 будет, но подарки получат двое. Это называется "состояние гонки". Решается либо в транзакции чтением с блокировкой, что бы никто другой не мог прочитать пока вы не закончите, либо более хитрым update. (`update tab set X=X-1 where X > 0`) с проверкой кол-ва измененных записей